# Find all separating sets of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let $G$ be a connected graph. A subset $S$ of $V(G)$ *separates* $G$, if the graph $G-S$ obtained from $G$ by deleting the vertices of $S$ is disconnected.

The original motivation was to find the toughness of a graph.

**Toughness**  is  defined as
$$
t(G)= \min _S \frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}
$$
where $c$ is the number of connected components, and the minimum is taken over all separating set $S$ of $G$ (Chvátal 1973).

So, in order to find the toughness of a graph, I attempt to find all separating sets beforehand. Otherwise  we would need to traverse all vertex subsets of the graph with sizes $\ge 1$ and less than the number of vertices minus 1.

```
s={2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7,   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7}
g1=Graph[s];
 vs = Subsets[VertexList[g1], {1, 6}];
 Min[Length[#]/ 
    Length@ConnectedGraphComponents[VertexDelete[g1, #]] & /@ vs]
```

Comment: perhaps using `IGMinimalSeparators[g1]` instead of `vs`?

Comment: @kglr A good attempt. I admit that in general, minimal separating sets are more interesting. However, if I replace "separating set" with "arbitrary minimal separating set " in the definition of  toughness, will it make a difference?